# How can CCSM's "Show Desktop" animation be made quicker?

Tags: unity, compiz, animations

In CCSM, under General Options, Key Bindings, there is a "Show Desktop" action. I use it quite often but the animation is too slow for me. Is there a way to speed it up (or turn it off)?

Comment: Have you tried other means? For example, pressing control+alt+D together? Or you could look at http://maketecheasier.com/accessing-the-show-desktop-icon-in-ubuntu-12-10/2012/10/26 for other ways.

Comment: Well, those are just another means to actually hsow the desktop. I am fine with using super+D, just the fade out animation takes too long for me.